# configtxgen command unable to identify Admin certs

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to use configtxgen tool for creating the necessary artifacts.

For certificates - I use fabric ca

The folder structure is as follows

```
Org1MSP  
-admincerts  
-signcerts  
-keystore  
-cacerts
```

Certificate files inside signcerts and admincerts are different. The keystore contains the private key of signcerts.

In configtx.yaml , I have mentioned Role.ADMIN for Org1MSP

1. Starting peer node is successful
2. Creating a Channel fails - Following is the error message
   "This identity is not an admin". ( My understanding is configtxgen command while constructing channel artifact, did not read certificate inside admincerts folder)

NOTE** 
If I copy the signcerts file into admincerts folder, it works fine.

Let me know how to proceed if I need unique peer certificate (sign cert for node) and admin certificate.